# Is it possible to have to call the Google AJAX Feed API twice on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, feed

I was thinking of using a slider panel to display two different feed-sections.
For example pulling in Tech in one div, and Sports in another..

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it possible for you to include the feed API once, and call it twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The documentation even has an example:

http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/ajaxfeeds/documentation/#FEEDCONTROL

This example fetches two feeds in one call. But nothing will stop you from fetching two feeds after another.

Comment: Thanks, never really thought of that.. just simply making another div with other ID and adding the JS needed. Thanks!